# Not able to disable incognito mode in chrome with windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, private-browsing

I have windows 8 and chrome version 28 but the steps which was said with the links below is not working. It still shows me incognito mode as enabled.

http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability

or

http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoEnabled

I did all the steps as mentioned and restarted the system too. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: In that case worth to uninstall the Chrome and download latest version and install it and set it again, it will not take too much if you have sync your account with Chrome.

Comment: How about running Chrome as Administrator?  Does that work?

Answer (score -1):

possibly either "reset browser settings" in settings or just reinstall if you have a google account. If you check "continue where I left off" in settings all your open webpages will even reopen after a reinstall and signing in.